# WEBM video looks correct in browsers, but not in video players

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

Ive been trying to figure out why a webm video renders incorrectly on my desktop...

The correct file can be seen [here](http://stelar7.no/webm/base.webm), however, downloading the file, and trying to play it in VLC/MPC-HC produces a bad video [as seen here](http://stelar7.no/webm/output.mp4)
(File is tested bad in VLC and MPC-HC, but renders perfectly in chrome and FF)

I've been able to extract the alpha channel with ffmpeg and [it looks correct](http://stelar7.no/webm/overlay.mp4)

Is this a poor implementation from the video players? (Other webm files play fine)
**Is there a command i can throw into ffmpeg (or similar) to get the webm to look ok?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the regular video players are showing is just the luma+color planes. You need a premultiplied result for the output you want. Which is what the browsers are doing, in effect. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43017337/5726027

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i base.webm -vf premultiply=inplace=1 out.mp4
```

Comment: Perfect! but for various reasons i need the output to be a webm file. and if i replace .mp4 with .webm it gets grainy.. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Add `-b:v 0 -crf 20`